# Printing barcode on zebra zt410 ">6c" missing characters

Tags: barcode, zebra-printers, zpl

I am printing a barcode Code 128 on a zebra printer. This is the text behind the barcode "D1>6>6C;-02-0"

It prints the barcode but when scanned by a scanner it only registers

D1>6>C;-02-0

As you can see the second 6 is missing.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Could you add the ZPL you're sending to the printer?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for. This is the string I am sending to the printer D1>>66>>66C;-02-0

Comment: just as an FYI the first >6 scans as >6 but I had to pass it in as >>66 to get it to scan as >6...... but when I pass in >>66C it scans as >C and ignores the 6

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because >6 is an invocation character for Code 128 barcodes on Zebra printers. See page 75 of the [ZPL Programming Guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf), but the gist of it is that invocation characters are not included in the field data when the barcode is generated.

The solution is to use >0 in the ^FD when you want a > printed. This means the string

```
D1>6>6C;-02-0
```

would have to be sent to the printer as

```
D1>06>06C;-02-0
```

I sent this to the printer using the following ZPL:

```
^XA
^FO100,100^BY3
^BCN,100,Y,N,N
^FDD1>06>06C;-02-0^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: When I send that to the printer it scans as D1>06>06C;-02-0

Comment: and the first >6 scans by changing it to >>6. But when I replace >6C with >>6C it scans as >C and ignores the 6.

Comment: How are you sending this to the printer? When I send it with the following ZPL, it works: `^XA
^FO100,100^BY3
^BCN,100,Y,N,N
^FDD1>06>06C;-02-0^FS
^XZ`

Comment: Also, what printer are you using?

Comment: I am using  software called unibar. I send it the string to print and it converts it to ZPL and send it to the printer.

Comment: I am using a Zebra ZT410 printer

Comment: This should work on the ZT410. I'm guessing it's something to do with the ZPL the app is using. I would reach out to the company